# MySQL - Search and replace text (".html") from dynamic url's that exists in href attributes, inside content columns

Tags: html, mysql, regex, sql-like

I am trying to create a MySQL query with a regex reference in order to correct a data entry mistake in my blog. Specifically I need to locate some **internal links** in my articles that the href value ends with ".html" (including the dot) and remove that part which is the mistake. These links should be without .html extension. Of course this is not so simple as that.

**THE PROBLEM**: I have many external links that ends up with this extension too (.html), which I dont want to change at all. I only want to change some of my internal links that ends with .html. Also these links are relative. So the query must be more complex in order to find only these links content (appr. 6000 articles).

The good part is that these links I need to search have already a pattern. This is an example `index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=6238:alias-title-of-an-article.html` (Yes, it is a Joomla installation with K2)

So my first thought was to create a query that comes with 2 conditions. A) Search for all links that href value starts with `index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=` and remove the ending part of it `.html` (If any exists). So far I have managed to do that:

**REGEX Ref:** `href="index\.php\?option=com_k2.*?(?=")`

**MySQL Query:** `UPDATE 'qc95t_k2_items' SET 'introtext' = REPLACE('introtext', '.html', '') WHERE 'catid'=84 AND 'introtext' LIKE '%href="index\.php\?option=com_k2.*?(?=")%';`

Except from the fact that this query is 100% wrong because it will select all references with `.html` it also returnes 0 results as it cannot find anything. Also In this example below my regex reference is working (I think) exept the "ends with .html" condition.

[REGEX Ref Example](https://regex101.com/r/dTi7qx/1)

I appreciate your help with that.

Comment: You can't do this with MySQL alone (at least, not without installing a UDF), as MySQL's native text replacement functions simply aren't powerful enough to distinguish instances of the search text in this manner.  I recommend that you instead write a script to fetch the records and perform the replacements using a library that's better suited to this task (e.g. something that can properly understand context within your `introtext` fields, such as an HTML parser)—you might still use a pattern in a `WHERE` condition to filter MySQL's results to only those that are likely candidates.

Comment: As regards your query above, note that MySQL's `LIKE` operator (which you're using) only performs simple pattern matching; to use regular expressions you must use `RLIKE` or `REGEXP` (which are synonyms) instead.  In this case, a simple pattern match might suffice: `WHERE introtext LIKE '%index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=%'`. Note also that you're quoting SQL object identifiers with single quote `'` characters, which isn't valid syntax—if you want/need to quote object identifiers, you should use backtick `\`` characters or (if `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode is enabled) double-quote `"` characters.

Comment: Why do you need regex here? Wouldn't a `LIKE '%href="index\.php\?option=com_k2%' suffice?`

Comment: @eggyal you are right about the syntax, the problem was with stackoverflow editor, it wouldnt allow me to add ```. Altthough just now, I think I understood how its done... :p

Comment: As for RLIKE and REGEXP I tried them but the results was again zero (0) just like LIKE. Anyway thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @LanceToth I tried that but it doesn't bring any results. Probably because LIKE only performs simple pattern matching as fellow eggyal mentioned earlier. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a workthrough on my own. Since it is mostly impossible to create such a complex query with regex replacements (REPLACE + REGEXP) directly through a MySQL Query, the solution I found is this:

1. Simply download (Export) the particular table (table.sql)
2. Open it with Notepad++ editor
3. Create a regex that matches 2 groups of strings. The first group will contain the url part up to ".html" (in this case it would be `"index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=6238:alias-title-of-an-article`) and the second group which will contain only the part that you want to be removed (in this case it would be `.html`)
4. Search and replace using Notepad++ adding the below regex command

**SEARCH:** `([^href="]*"index\.php\?option=com_k2&amp;view=item&amp;id=\d{2,4}:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[\w\-]*)\.html`

**REPLACE WITH:** `$1`

5. Save and Upload your table back to your database

The above Regex command (Search field) groups the url except the ".html" part and on Replace (`$1`) it tells to Notepad to replace all but keep the 1st group which is the proper url without `.html`. This works tottaly (Tested) and in my case I have cleaned up 658 urls. Below you can find the Regex in action:

[REGEX Command](https://regex101.com/r/RyTBd0/1)